# Forms OneToMany foreign key null violation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When I submitting form and persisting Object model I got `SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "object_id"` error.

I have two Doctrine entities:

```php
class Object {
    /**
     * @var Document[]|ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="mainObject", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $documents;
}
```

```php
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Object", inversedBy="documents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $object;
}
```

and Symfony form:

```php
class ObjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('documents', CollectionType::class, [
                'allow_add' => true,
                'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

My controller code:

```php
$object = new Object();
$form = $this->formFactory->create(ObjectType::class, $object);
$form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true), false);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->entityManager->persist($object);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

The error occurs because the Doctrine saves the Document before the Object. Is it possible to change the save behaviour?

Comment: What does your `addDocument` method look like on your object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can use `by_reference => false` on the collection type. By setting this to false, you are saying always use the methods rather than accessing the property.

```php
$builder
    ->add('documents', CollectionType::class, [
        'allow_add' => true,
        'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
        'by_reference' => false,
    ]);
```

In some cases, the property will be used directly rather than the methods. You can read more about this property [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference).

You will also want to set the object when adding a new document on your `addDocument()` method on the object. This should look something like:

```php
public function addDocument(Document $document): object
{
    $document->setObject($this);

    $this->getDocuments()->add($document);

    return $this;
}
```

That should solve your problem. I also think having an entity named `object` is a bit confusing.